# is there any mistake in adding border to tableViewCell bottom edge for particular row alone from below code

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Below code is working but when I scroll the tableview multiple times, the border started appearing for other cells as well. can any one suggest the solutions.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let separator = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: cell.frame.size.height - 1, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 1))

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

            if items.count == 4 {
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray()
                    cell.contentView.addSubview(separator)
                }else {
                separator.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }else {
            separator.removeFromSuperview()
            }

    }else {
    separator.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the line: separator.removeFromSuperview(); does nothing in your code. You did not call the desired separator.

better practice may be to add separator to every cell and hide/unhide it by using the UITableView cellForRow func.